# Unattended Xamarin iOS iPad kiosk app crashing sometimes (new, from months in app store)

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a kiosk app that I've developed using Xamarin Forms for iPad.

This kiosk app has a credit card reader and Bluetooth barcode scanner attached.

The App Store version 1.0.4 has been out since November 2017 with no issues. In the last month or so, we have been getting reports from my customers that the iPads are frozen (App is locked up). I did some research into the crash logs and found a Springboard Watchdog timeout (10 sec) due to a web service API call I was making was on the UI thread was timing out. Contacted the web service owner and found they had some server issues causing slow responsiveness. I modified the app to make all web API calls on a background thread, and thought that should alleviate the issue. I find out the iPads are still freezing up but this time there is no crash log.

Fast forward about 5 revisions (now using Testflight) and I'm on version 1.0.9. I've added a lot of logging, pinging every 10 minutes, a LOT of try/catch calls around all methods with logs to try and isolate the problem. I've been unsuccessful.

So here we are, iPads freezing up all over the place, logs not indicating how or why they are locking up. However the kiosks are locked up and require someone to quit Guided Access mode, close the app and restart the app.

So I have the most recent example below, these are the last log entries before the device went offline (stopped pinging).

Newest log entries are first
Id  LogTime LocationCodeId  LogMessage

> 61872 2018-05-11 08:45:50.223 61  Logging into location A19Bb2bc ...
>
> 61871 2018-05-11 08:45:50.210 61  Opening Magtek card reader device ...

(... nothing else here in the logs but at this point the app is frozen on the screen...) it's not crashed, just frozen the UI is unresponsive to touch. Needs to be force quit from iPad double-top home button, swipe up.

> 61576 2018-05-11 07:24:33.870 61  Order placed successfully
>
> 61577 2018-05-11 07:24:33.870 61  Restart
>
> 61575 2018-05-11 07:24:33.263 61  Start scanner trigger
>
> 61574 2018-05-11 07:24:33.217 61  Trigger scanner start
>
> 61573 2018-05-11 07:24:33.027 61  Product Honey Nut Cheerios (cup)
> (Id:5038 AssetId:35 Price:$1.79 removed from cart. Cart total is $0.00

After that log entry "order placed" the ViewModel (normally) does a Navigation.PopAsync(true) and goes back to the idle view. However there are no more log entries after this. This is a working example log:

There are no background threads, no weird blocking, no database calls etc. This is a simple Log to our Logging API, then pop the shopping cart off the nav stack and back to idle.

> 61329 2018-05-11 05:13:08.560 61  Ping timer
>
> 61327 2018-05-11 05:12:09.490 61  IdleView OnAppearing done
>
> 61326 2018-05-11 05:12:09.443 61  ShoppingCartView OnDisappearing
>
> 61324 2018-05-11 05:12:09.413 61  IdleView OnAppearing
>
> 61323 2018-05-11 05:12:09.383 61  Stopping barcode scanner ...
>
> 61321 2018-05-11 05:12:08.710 61  Order placed successfully
>
> 61322 2018-05-11 05:12:08.710 61  Restart
>
> 61319 2018-05-11 05:12:07.820 61  Start scanner trigger

The symbolicated crash log can be found here:

https://pastebin.com/urNsFA4z

```
Links to pastebin.com must be accompanied by code?
```

I can't figure out what the crash log is saying. There is not one line in the crash log pointing to any of my source code, which makes me think this is an async/threading issue or some other unhandled exception.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Received this response from Apple about the crash log:

Follow-up: 689674112
The reason the crash log isn’t helpful is, it’s not a real crash.

Your app is terminated becasue Xamarin called abort() on the main thread.
It did this after trying to handle an exception, and when it could not, it gave up and aborted the app.

Why this is happening, I can’t tell you. But it is likely not due to something on the main thread, but rather, the Xamarin exception handler was on the main thread.

I see that threads 8 and 9 are waiting on something (hopefully not in a deadlock). Other than that, I would have no way of knowing what Xamarin considers an exception.

This might be the time to look for some help from Xamarin resources to solve this problem.

---

 Developer Technical Support

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced similar symptoms (sudden freezes and odd crashes) in an app that had severe memory leaks. I would recommend making some testing using a profiler.

[Xamarin Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/?tabs=vsmac) (Requires Enterprise subscription) / [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH3-SW1)

Comment: Not sure it's a memory leak, the app isn't doing much but I will have a look at the Xamarin profiler. Thank you.